# Powershell - CloseMainWindow work for all?

Tags: powershell, process, google-drive-api, terminate

I'm looking for a way to gracefully close/quit the GoogleDrive app which runs under the process GoogleDriveFS.

```
get-process GoogleDriveFS

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    219      16    10796       5732       0.05   4392   1 GoogleDriveFS
    333      22    11820      32364       0.17   8424   1 GoogleDriveFS
    297      19    16528      34860       0.06  12036   1 GoogleDriveFS
    245      17    10472      23992       0.03  14296   1 GoogleDriveFS
    572      26    52256      82728       0.84  17788   1 GoogleDriveFS
    518      21    28668      68208       0.44  18460   1 GoogleDriveFS
   1024      59    47016      89396      27.95  19452   1 GoogleDriveFS
```

is something like Process.CloseMainWindow Method suitable for this ? or is there a better way to ensure the app isn't running?

Comment: might be useful: https://superuser.com/questions/1682641/how-to-check-if-process-is-running-properly-in-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

[`System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow) will *not* work, for the reasons explained in the bottom section.

Note:

- If the target processes weren't started from your own user account, you'll need to run the following from an *elevated* (run as admin) session.

You can ***try*** the following to achieve ***graceful* termination**, but there's no guarantee it will work:

```sh
# Asks all GoogleDriveFS processes to terminate, which they may or may not do.
# A status line is output to stdout for each targeted process, 
# indicating whether the termination request was successfully *sent*.
# Note: ".exe" must be used, whereas it mustn't be 
#       with PowerShell's *-Process cmdlets.
taskkill.exe /im GoogleDriveFS.exe
```

If it doesn't, ***forceful* termination** is your only option, which is most easily accomplished with:

```sh
# !! Forcefully terminates all GoogleDriveFS, without cleanup.
Stop-Process -Force -Name GoogleDriveFS
```

<sup>Note: As discussed below, `Stop-Process` *always* terminates forcefully. The only function of the `-Force` switch is to suppress a potential confirmation prompt that is presented when you attempt to terminate processes belonging to a different user (only works with elevation).</sup>

Here's a **snippet that first tries graceful termination, then falls back to forceful termination after a specifiable timeout**:

```sh
$processName = 'GoogleDriveFS'
$timeOutSecs = 2

# Get all existing processes of interest.
$processes = Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore -Name $processName

if (-not $processes) {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "No $processName processes running."
} else {
  # Ask the processes to terminate, which they may or may not do.
  taskkill.exe /im "$processName.exe" *>$null 
  try { 
   # Wait for up to $timeOutSecs seconds for the processes to - 
   # potentially - terminate gracefully.
   $processes | Wait-Process -ErrorAction Stop -Timeout $timeOutSecs
  } catch {
    Write-Warning "Forcefully terminating (remaining) $processName processes..."
    # Note: This assumes that you don't care about any new 
    #       processes that may have launched since Get-Process was called.
    $processes | Stop-Process -Force
  }
}
```

---

- **On Windows, *graceful* termination is fundamentally only an option for GUI-subsystem applications**, i.e. processes that have a main window (whether visible or not) and therefore a *message loop* to which the `WM_CLOSE` message can be posted.

  - In other words: **you cannot ask *console* applications on Windows to terminate gracefully** (unless they implement some application-specific custom mechanism through which other processes can request termination).
  - For supported applications, there are **important considerations**:

    - Termination *isn't guaranteed*, and even if it does happen, its *timing* isn't guaranteed:

      - The target process may be in a state where it cannot process the `WM_CLOSE` message, such as when it happens to be displaying a modal dialog at the time or happens to be stuck.
      - The target process may quietly refuse to terminate.
      - The target process may put up a modal dialog to confirm the intent to terminate, notably when trying to close an editor-like application that has an unsaved document open.
    - Therefore, **if you need to *ensure* termination**, you'll have to monitor the process for actual termination afterwards, and **possibly terminate it *forcefully* after a suitable timeout period**.

      - [`taskkill.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) offers forceful termination via its `/f` option.
      - .NET offers forceful termination via [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill)

        - As an aside: **As of PowerShell 7.2.x, the [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) cmdlet *invariably*** uses this method, i.e. invariably **terminates processes *forcefully*** - allowing requesting *graceful* termination on an opt-in basis is the subject of [GitHub issue #13664](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13664#issuecomment-777935849).
- **At the Windows API level, it doesn't matter if the targeted main window is visible or not**, so that even (GUI-subsystem) processes that by design run *invisibly* - [as `GoogleDriveFS.exe` appears to be](https://www.file.net/process/googledrivefs.exe.html) - can be targeted with a `WM_CLOSE` message.

  - While **[`System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow)** *is* designed to request graceful termination of a given process by sending a `WM_CLOSE` message to its main window, it unfortunately **doesn't find that window *if it happens to be invisible (hidden)*** (still applies as of .NET 6.0)
  - By contrast, the **[`taskkill.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) utility does *not* have this limitation**.
  - A **limitation that BOTH methods share is the inability to target processes that are *[UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) / Microsoft Store applications***.

    - However, this **applies only to "pure" UWP applications** (e.g, Settings, Calculator), and not to desktop applications *packaged as* UWP apps (e.g., Windows Terminal, Microsoft Edge).
    - The reason is that both methods rely on the [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) WinAPI method, which only supports desktop applications.
    - However, *manually* finding a UWP application's main window via [`FindWindowEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa) and posting `WM_CLOSE` to it, *is* possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
do {
    $running = try { Get-Process -Name GoogleDriveFS -ErrorAction Stop } catch { Write-Host "Error: $($PSItem.Exception.Message) " }
    $running | ForEach-Object {
        
        $_.CloseMainWindow()
        Write-Debug -Message "Closing ($_).pm "
    
    }
}
until ($running -eq $null)
```

However, this will prompt for the user to confirm the close.

You could also use the `close()` method to avoid prompting the user or `kill()` to immediately release all resources.

> **CloseMainWindow()**
> Closes a process that has a user interface by sending a close message to its main window.

> **Close()** Frees all the resources that are associated with this component.

> **Kill()** Immediately stops the associated process.

via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0#methods

Comment: Unfortunately, `.CloseMainWindow()` won't work with processes whose main windows is _hidden_, which I think is the case here. `.Close()` has no effect on the target process at all - it simply frees the resources associated with _its representation in .NET_

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `--quit` argument of **GoogleDriveFS.exe** :

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\64.0.4.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe" --quit
```

But it will break after each software update so running **this bat file should be better** :

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Google\Drive File Stream\launch.bat" --quit
```

This bat file looks up the latest GoogleDriveFS.exe and runs it with the same arguments as the script.

And from Powershell :

```
Start-Process -FilePath "${env:ProgramFiles}\Google\Drive File Stream\launch.bat" -ArgumentList '--quit' -Wait -NoNewWindow
```