# Trapping a PowerShell Statement from Win32_Process into a Variable for Taskkill Command

Tags: powershell

This powershell statement looks for a long commandline string from a process java.exe - it uses the string server1 to trap this specific process.  It returns the words `Processid` and `Commandline` with its relative values.

```
gwmi win32_process | select Processid,Commandline | where-object CommandLine -match "server1"
```

returns this line where `15112` is all I need:

```
Processid Commandline                                         
--------- -----------                                         
    15112 D:\ ..a long command string.
```

How would you trap the single PID number returned from the above PS statement in a variable to run a `taskkill /pid $PIDNUM` on ?  Not sure how to extract that single number from the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, we store the entire result into the variable `$PIDNUM`, and we can access the result object's properties using dot-notation

```
$PIDNUM = (gwmi win32_process | select Processid,Commandline | where-object CommandLine -match "server1").ProcessID
taskkill /pid $PIDNUM
```

or

```
$PIDNUM = gwmi win32_process | select Processid,Commandline | where-object CommandLine -match "server1"
taskkill /pid $PIDNUM.ProcessID
```

If your first statement finds multiple tasks, you'll need to run a loop to execute the taskkill for each object stored in the `$PIDNUM` variable

```
foreach ($num in $PIDNUM)
{
    taskkill /pid $num.processid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the obligatory pointer:

- The **CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets** (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`, whose built-in alias is `gwmi`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

```
$pidOfInterest = 
  (
    Get-CimInstance win32_process |
      Where-Object CommandLine -match server1
  ).ProcessId
```

Note:

- `$pidOfInterest` may receive *multiple* PIDs (process IDs), given that multiple processes may match your `Where-Object` filter; that accessing `.ProcessId` directly on a potential *array* of values still works to extract its *elements'* property values is courtesy of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature.

  - If `$pidOfInterest` does end up containing *multiple* PIDs, you can pass them to `taskkill.exe` as follows:

    ```
    taskkill $pidOfInterest.ForEach({ '/pid', $_ })
    ```
  - With `Stop-Process` (see below), it is simpler, because its `-Id` parameter accepts an *array* of PIDs:

    ```
    Stop-Process -Id $pidOfInterest
    ```
- The `select Processid,Commandline` part of your command just creates unnecessary overhead, so it was omitted above - the `Get-CimInstance` output objects can be filtered directly.
- You don't strictly need [`taskkill.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) for terminating processes, given that PowerShell has a [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) cmdlet.

  - However, an important difference is that `taskkill.exe` attempts *graceful, cooperative* termination by default, whereas `Stop-Process` (as of PowerShell 7.2.3) invariably terminates *forcefully* - which is what `taskkill.exe` offers as an *opt-int* with `/f`

    - Improving `Stop-Process` in the future to support graceful, cooperative termination too is the subject of [GitHub issue #13664](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13664#issuecomment-777935849).
  - Attempting graceful termination means that termination *may not be effective*, however.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71803366/45375) for more information.